# shift data in a column conditionally using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a df like this

```
index   shift   value
0         1       A
1         0       nan
2         0       A 
3         1       A
4         0       nan
5         0       nan
6         0       A
7         0       nan
```

after the code, the desirable output is like this: only the value has a 1 on shift moves down a row

```
index   shift   value
0         1       nan
1         0       A
2         0       A 
3         1       nan
4         0       A
5         0       nan
6         0       A
7         0       nan
```

the 1 in shift column will only happen where there's a nonna value on the value column. I was thinking of using shift(), but it will shift the whole column value downwards which is not what I want.

Comment: Have you made an attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['value'] = df.loc[np.arange(len(df)) - df['shift'].shift().fillna(0),'value'].to_numpy()
df['value'] = df['value'].where(df['shift'].eq(0))
```

or

```
df['value'].fillna((v:=df.loc[df['shift'].ne(0)]).set_axis(v.index + v['shift'])['value']).where(df['shift'].eq(0))
```

or

```
(v:=df.loc[df['shift'].eq(1)]).set_axis(v.index + (v['shift']))['value'].reindex(np.arange(len(df))).fillna(df.loc[df['shift'].eq(0),'value'])
```